# Eclipse : how to use azure storage in android NDK ?

Tags: android-ndk, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

Actually, I work with azure storage and mobiles services. In my work, I had to do two tests :

1. Test azure mobile service using android java
2. Test azure mobile service using android ndk

Firtly test i done, work fine. I passed to second test but i don't have great idea of how to do it. 

[azure storage for c++ github repo](http://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp)

[Using azure storage with c++ example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-blobs/)

I checked these docs, for look how to do it.
Need help to done this test. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your question really is, whether you are having challenges with Storage or Mobile services.
If you are looking to try out the android client library for Storage, please check this out: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android

Comment: Here's a sample that uses it with Mobile Services: https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/UploadImages